# Toggle case sensitivity for a huge chunk of Clojure code

Tags: clojure

There is a large chunk of code (mostly not mine) that does the following with user input (that is more or less, space separated list of commands with some arguments/options):

1. Remove all unsupported characters
2. Split on space into a vector
3. Recursively apply first item in vector on the rest of the vector (function uses whatever arguments it needs, and returns vector without itself and its arguments to the loop).

Functions themselves, as far as input is concerned, have a mix of (case), (cond), (condp), (=) and (compare) with some nasty (keyword) comparisons mixed in.

Everyone was fine with the fact that this all is strictly case-sensitive until very recently. Now some (previously unknown) ancient integration bits acting as users appeared and are having some casing issues that I have no control over.

Question: is there a viable way (shortcut before there will be more time to redo it all) to make string comparison case insensitive for some sort of a scope, based on some variable?

I considered 3 options:

1. Fixing the code (will be done sometime, anyway, but not viable at the moment).
2. Extracting some low level comparison function (hopefully just one) and rebinding it for the local scope (sounds great, but catching cases might be difficult and error-prone).
3. Standardize input (might not be possible without some hacks since some data, outside comparisons, NEEDS to be case sensitive).

After some research, the answer is probably no (and planning for major changes should start), but I figured asking would not hurt, maybe someone thought of it before.

Edit: sample problematic input:

```
"Command1 ARG1 aRG2 Command3 command9 Arg4 Arg9 aRg5 COMMAND4 arg8"
```

Breaking it down:
"Commands" with broken case I need to be able, on demand, to match case insensitively. Arguments are matched case insensitively on another level - so they do not concern this piece of code, but their case inside this bit of code should be preserved to be sent further along.
NB! It is not possible at the start of the processing to tell what is in the input a command and what is argument.

Comment: For `case`: No way. For anything that uses `=` you can `refer-clojure` and exclude `=` and define it yourself (checking if both are strings and do a case-insensitive comparison).

Comment: You will need to add more details (example code & data) to get a precise answer. In the meantime, why can't you just use `str/lower-case` on all input prior to processing?

Comment: @Alan Code is not mine, unfortunately. It is relatively simple, but there is a lot of it. str/lower-case I cannot apply on the input before any processing, as some data manipulation requires case sensitivity to be preserved.
And adding it with and if condition to every single comparison will take a huge amount of time.
Will add input example in a sec.

Comment: I found a solution when writing the edit that I totally missed. Recursive function that processes the list always knows that first item on the list is not and argument, so I can make it case insensitive in that one place and than just change all the (case) statements with regexp.

Comment: What happens to the *result* of applying the first item in the vector to as many subsequent items as it requires?

Comment: There are no results, only side effects (logging, saving some of the things to the database or throwing errors). 
Is it worth adding my own answer if I cannot provide any code example for code/solution? I would prefer to accept comment from @ClojureMostly or Alan Thompson, since the workaround was the mix of both plus some regular expressions to standardize the case of string in (case) macro.

Comment: The accepted practice is to write and accept your own answer, giving credit where it's due. You're allowed to give yourself a pay rise here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As per [Alan Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1822379/alan-thompson)'s comment, `str/lower-case` was the right first half of approach - I just needed to find the right place to apply it to just command name.
2. Afterwards redefining `=` and couple of functions used inside `cond` and `condp` (credit to [ClojureMostly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/684167/clojuremostly)) solved the matching part.
3. All that was left were the string literals inside `case` statements which I just find-and-replaced with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here is a case-insensitive wrapper for simple `case` forms:

```
(ns lexer.core)

(defn- standardize [thing]
  (assert (string? thing) (str thing " should be a string"))
  (clojure.string/lower-case thing))

(defmacro case-insensitive-case [expr & pairs+default?]
  (let [pairs (partition 2 pairs+default?)
        convert (fn [[const form]]
                  (list (standardize const) form))
        most-of-it `(case (standardize ~expr) ~@(mapcat convert pairs))]
    (if (-> pairs+default? count even?)
      most-of-it
      (concat most-of-it [(last pairs+default?)]))))
```

For example,

```
(macroexpand-1 '(case-insensitive-case (test expression) 
                                       "Blam!" (1 + 1) 
                                       (whatever works)))
=> (clojure.core/case (lexer.core/standardize (test expression)) "blam!" (1 + 1) (whatever works))
```

The `assert` in `standardize` is necessary because `lower-case` turns things into strings:

```
(clojure.string/lower-case 22)
=> "22"
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but this would be overkill for people that would have to look at it afterwards. 
Since case expressions are all compile-time literals it was much easier for us to just standardize all of the literals into one case with regexp directly in code.